# How to do a one line while loop with initialization of the loop variable on the same line?

Tags: python, while-loop, one-liner

Consider

```
a=2;s=0;while s<11: print(s*a);s+=1
```

I am getting

```
    a=2;s=0;while s<11: print(s*a);s+=1
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want everything in a single line. Is it possible?

---

The reasoning for monstrosities like this is to try and beat a [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do you need a `while`? Here, this is basically just a loop over `range(11)`. Something like `a=2;print(*(s*a for s in range(11)), sep="\n")`, or `a=2;print("\n".join(str(s*a) for s in range(11)))`.

Comment: _"I want everything in a single line."_ Why though? Putting everything in a single line doesn't speed up your code or have any tangible benefits.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I am doing very ugly and hacky things to try and beat a code golf. Doing what I have to do.

Comment: @12944qwerty `a=2;s=0;while s<11: print(s*a)` gives the same (compilation) error. The problem is *before* the while.

Comment: Ah, that's where the confusion came. Please put the full traceback then.

Comment: @12944qwerty see edit please.